# Расположение изображения в header над Grid (HTML)

Tags: html, css, html5, css-grid

Необходимо в Header, не входящий в Grid-сетки, расположить (без повтора, но автомасштабированием) с отступами,  2fr и 2fr (left and right если ориентироваться на пропорции нижележащей Grid-сетки изображение.[image: В рамках "синей" области]. Как это сделать? Перепробовал много разных вариантов - от align до margin или даже устаревших html тэгов отступа по горизонтали.

[Сам сайт:](https://munister-v.github.io/) https://munister-v.github.io/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Example</title>
<style>

  .header
  { 
  height: 8em;
  padding: 2em 10%;      
  }




.head_img
  {
  background: url(img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
  margin-left: 2f;
  margin-right: 2f;
  }


.header,
.footer {
  background-color: Gold;
   height: 70px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #49423d;
}

.main {
  background-color: DimGrey;

}

.m {
  background-color: Gray;
   height: 16.4%;
}

.header,
.main,
.aside,
.m,
.footer {
  border: solid 1px red;

}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {

  margin: auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height:100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 2fr;
}



/* Smartphones (вертикальная и горизонтальная) ----------- */  
@media only screen and (min-width : 350px) and (max-width : 641px)
{
  .grid-container 
  {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  .aside 
  {
  display: none;
   }

  }

}


</style>  

 <body>
  <div class="page">   
    <div class="header"><div class="head_img"><img src="img/Header.jpg"></div></div>


    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="aside">Left</div>
      <div class="main">Main</div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="m">Поиск</div>
        <div class="m">Свежие записи</div>
        <div class="m">Свежие комментарии</div>
        <div class="m">Архивы</div>
        <div class="m">Рубрики</div>
        <div class="m">Мета</div>
      </div>
      <div class="aside">Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - не задавать строгий отступ по бокам:

```css
    .header
    {
        height: 8em;
        padding: 2em 10%;
    }




    .head_img
    {
        background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 84%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        top: 0;
        height: 120px;
    }


    .header,
    .footer {
        background-color: Gold;
        height: 70px;
    }

    .aside {
        background-color: #49423d;
    }

    .main {
        background-color: DimGrey;

    }

    .m {
        background-color: Gray;
        height: 16.4%;
    }

    .header,
    .main,
    .aside,
    .m,
    .footer {
        border: solid 1px red;

    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .page {

        margin: auto;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height:100vh;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 2fr;
    }



    /* Smartphones (вертикальная и горизонтальная) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 350px) and (max-width : 641px)
    {
        .grid-container
        {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
        .header
        {
            height: 7em;
            padding: 0em 0%;
        }
        .head_img
        {
            background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            top: 0;
            height: 120px;
        }


        .aside
        {
            display: none;
        }

    }

    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header"><div class="head_img"></div></div>


    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="aside">Left</div>
        <div class="main">Main</div>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="m">Поиск</div>
            <div class="m">Свежие записи</div>
            <div class="m">Свежие комментарии</div>
            <div class="m">Архивы</div>
            <div class="m">Рубрики</div>
            <div class="m">Мета</div>
        </div>
        <div class="aside">Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Если при минимальном разрешении (Там где меняется у Вас через `@media` надо оставить отступы в header), то можно так:

```css
    .header
    {
        height: 8em;
        padding: 2em 10%;
    }




    .head_img
    {
        background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 84%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        top: 0;
        height: 120px;
    }


    .header,
    .footer {
        background-color: Gold;
        height: 70px;
    }

    .aside {
        background-color: #49423d;
    }

    .main {
        background-color: DimGrey;

    }

    .m {
        background-color: Gray;
        height: 16.4%;
    }

    .header,
    .main,
    .aside,
    .m,
    .footer {
        border: solid 1px red;

    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .page {

        margin: auto;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height:100vh;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 2fr;
    }



    /* Smartphones (вертикальная и горизонтальная) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 350px) and (max-width : 641px)
    {
        .grid-container
        {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }



        .aside
        {
            display: none;
        }

    }

    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header"><div class="head_img"></div></div>


    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="aside">Left</div>
        <div class="main">Main</div>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="m">Поиск</div>
            <div class="m">Свежие записи</div>
            <div class="m">Свежие комментарии</div>
            <div class="m">Архивы</div>
            <div class="m">Рубрики</div>
            <div class="m">Мета</div>
        </div>
        <div class="aside">Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```